# Is it possible to impute multiple values from a different dataframe dependent on a condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I have the following dataframe...

```
# Starting dataframe
data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Excluded, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC, ~col_mean, ~varA, ~varB,
  "A", TRUE,      1,     1,     1,     1,         "X",   10,
  "B", FALSE,     NA,    2,     2,     NA,        "Y",   20,
  "C", FALSE,     3,     3,     3,     3,         "Z",   30
)
```

And a subsetted dataframe (i.e. fewer observations exist) where missing values have been imputed, e.g. ...

```
# Dataframe with imputed values
data_imputed <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Excluded, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC, ~col_mean, ~varA, ~varB,
  "B", FALSE,     2,     2,     2,     2,         "Y",   20,
  "C", FALSE,     3,     3,     3,     3,         "Z",   30
)
```

How do I replace values in the original dataframe with those from the imputed dataframe when a particular column (e.g. `col_mean`) has a missing value?

*Note: I don't want to replace the whole row with the row from the imputed dataframe, just a specified set of columns (e.g., in this case, those starting with "col").*

The target dataframe would look like this...

```
# Target dataframe
data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Excluded, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC, ~col_mean, ~varA, ~varB,
  "A", TRUE,      1,     1,     1,     1,         "X",   10,
  "B", FALSE,     2,     2,     2,     2,         "Y",   20,
  "C", FALSE,     3,     3,     3,     3,         "Z",   30
)
```

I have tried to summarise the problem with this figure...

[image]

I need to do this for four or five sets of columns, so something where I can specify the condition (e.g. `is.na(col_mean)`) and the columns to use (using regex) would make things easier.

I tend to use tidyverse, so code that works with tidyverse syntax is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `rows_` family from `dplyr`. In this case, `rows_patch()` works well. It modifies existing rows by some key columns (i.e. `ID`), but only overwrites `NA` values.

```r
library(dplyr)

rows_patch(data, data_imputed, by = "ID")

# # A tibble: 3 × 8
#   ID    Excluded  colA  colB  colC col_mean varA   varB
#   <chr> <lgl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     TRUE         1     1     1        1 X        10
# 2 B     FALSE        2     2     2        2 Y        20
# 3 C     FALSE        3     3     3        3 Z        30
```

Comment: Wow, I've really fallen behind on dplyr verbs ... nice.

Answer (score 2):

```r
left_join(data, data_imputed, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ coalesce(., cur_data()[[sub("\\.x$", ".y", cur_column())]]))) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y")) %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~ sub("\\.x$", "", .))
# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#   ID    Excluded  colA  colB  colC col_mean varA   varB
#   <chr> <lgl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     TRUE         1     1     1        1 X        10
# 2 B     FALSE        2     2     2        2 Y        20
# 3 C     FALSE        3     3     3        3 Z        30
```

Comment: Hello, this is useful for swapping the values in the correct columns but it doesn't look as though it is conditional on whether the observation is missing in a specified column.

Comment: `coalesce` will replace the value in `data` with the value in `data_imputed` if and only if the value in `data` is `NA`. If you want the replacement to be only to a set of columns, then the `ends_with(".x")` should be adjusted (and/or we only join those columns plus `ID` from `data_imputed`). If you only want to _attempt_ replacement based on very specific row/column pairs, then ... you'll need to bake your own solution, I find the elegance and safety of this code useful enough to not try to make it more complicated.

Comment: This way works well if I want to replace all missing values, but I would like to be able to do this based on a condition i.e. a specified column has a missing value and for a subset of columns (but I can see how the above code can be adapted to specify the latter part).